# How to convert row to compute column value in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My SQL table is in the following format, how do I convert my table to give out CTR as a column?

```
    Date    |Type                       |count
    --------+---------------------------+------
    1-Apr   |Clicks                     |500
    1-Apr   |Impression                 |1000
    1-Apr   |distict user Clicks        |300
    1-Apr   |distict user impressions   |450
    2-Apr   |Clicks                     |520
    2-Apr   |Impression                 |1020
    2-Apr   |distict user Clicks        |320
    3-Apr   |distict user impressions   |470
```

I want this to become CTR (Clickthrough rate)
eg 1 April CTR = 500/1000 %   = 50%
eg 2 April CTR = 520/1020 %   = 42.30 %

```
Date    |CTR    |Distict User CTR
--------+-------+------------------
1-Apr   |50%    |66.60%
2-Apr   |42.30% |68.08





SELECT 
   date , 
   CalculateCTR,      <-- How? 
   calculate DISTINCT CTR
FROM Metrics
```

Answer (score 2):

A modified pivot query should work here:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    100.0*MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Clicks' THEN count END) /
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Impressions' THEN count END) AS CTR,
    100.0*MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'distinct user Clicks' THEN count END) /
        MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'distinct user impressions' THEN count END) AS "Distinct User CTR"
FROM Metrics
GROUP BY Date;
```

Comment: Why do we need `MAX`? I tried the above and getting `null`

Comment: Are you sure the `Type` column contains the _exact_ text `Clicks`, `Impressions`, etc., with _no whitespace_ present?  My query should be working.  `NULL` values indicate that there are missing types for certain dates, which is a problem with your data.